# in swift 3 on button click application is crash which bind with story board

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, selector, swift3

I have developed one project in Swift 2.2 and after Swift 3 launch I need to convert it in Swift 3 and make compilable with iOS 10. But after converting the project i face some issue like when I clicked on button which connected with storyboard my application is crash with give reason **unrecognized selector sent to instance** . It is working in swift 2.2 and i have not change any thing.

```
 @IBAction func btnTwitter_Clicked(sender:UIButton)
         {
              if checkInternetConnection()
              {
                    SINGLETON.startLoadingActivity(self.view);
                    let objLocationTracker = LocationTracker.sharedInstance
                    objLocationTracker.fetchCurrentLocation({ (objLocation) -> (Void) in
                        SINGLETON.stopLoadingActivity(self.view)
                        self.loginWithTwitter(objLocation: objLocation)
                        })
              }
              else
              {
                 SINGLETON.toast(read_Localizable("noInternet"),view: self.view)
              }
         }
```

Comment: I notice that you have put two '@' signs before your IBActions. Is this just a typo here or is it the same in your code too? Please check your code and remove extra '@'. Maybe this is causing the issue

Comment: @ShayanJalil this  mistake made in copr paste it is not in code

Comment: Why down vote? i don't think this is irrelevant question there are lot of person who face this and on SO there is no help available for this. Give at least reason

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but it could have been because you didn't share the full error message. The "unrecognized selector" portion tells you about the type of error, but the full error message tells us _which_ selector and object type the error occurred. Next time, share the full error message. Also, given that the problem could easily have been in the selector, you should have shared that portion of code, too. You're showing us a method that is what the selector calls, but doesn't show us the source of the problem, e.g. where you called `addTarget` or what have you.

Comment: @Rob thanks for your comment next time i take care about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this

**@@IBAction func btnTwitter_Clicked(sender:UIButton)** you were added the additional **@** in front of your button, check once ,

in swift3 we need to write the button action like

```
yourbuttonName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourVCName. btnTwitter_Clicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and call method as like

```
@IBAction func btnTwitter_Clicked(_ sender: UIButton){
   print("Button pressed  ")
  // continue your work

 }
```

or delete the button Outlets and IBActions and regenerate again once, surely works

Comment: Thanks for the answer but @@ is copy paste mistake it is not in code

Comment: so i need to convert all the button selector which is connected with storyboard right?

Comment: @chiragshah - absolutely  ,just delete the connection and regenrate once surely works

Answer (score 1):

Just delete all of your Outlets and IBActions from the connections inspector in the storyboard and add them again. Everything should work fine after that

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding action to button programmatically your selector syntax is something like `#selector(btnTwitter_Clicked(_:))` this is not work for Swift 3 as of from Swift 3 you need to specify the first parameter name so either add _ as first parameter name in your method like `func btnTwitter_Clicked(_ sender: UIButton)` or change your selector syntax like this one of this will solve your crash.

```
 #selector(btnTwitter_Clicked(sender:))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer let me try this

Comment: You save my day this is working so i need to convert all the button selector which is connected with storyboard right?

Comment: Yes , Happy to help :)